# Checkbox is only getting value from one checkbox. I need to get value for multiple checkboxes when selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'm having some issues trying to get the Checkbox to receive multiple values when checked. I'm using a dynamic GridView. When the Checkbox is checked and the Start button is clicked the services are suppose to start. Only one service is starting and the value for the other services that are Checked are reading false. I know I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Style="font-size: 15pt" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceName" HeaderText="Service Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkStatus" Enabled="True" runat="server"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>


protected void strBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ServiceName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

string include = txtbox_Inclusion.Text;
string exclude = txtbox_Exclusion.Text;

ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

foreach (ServiceController service in services)
{
    if (service.ServiceName.StartsWith(include) && !service.ServiceName.Contains(exclude))
    {
        var dro = dt.NewRow();
        dro["ServiceName"] = service.ServiceName;
        dro["Description"] = service.DisplayName;
        dro["Status"] = service.Status;
        dt.Rows.Add(dro);

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)//loop the GridView Rows
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("ChkStatus"); //find the CheckBox
            if (cb != null)
            {
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    service.Start();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                    dro["Status"] = service.Status;
                }
                else if (cb.Checked && service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    cb.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a suggestion but whenever you're looping through all items in a collection - whether it's a list or in your case `GridView1.Rows` - consider using LINQ's `foreach` loop. So in your case it would be `foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)`. It ensure you aren't missing any items and makes it much prettier and easier to read!

Comment: Please format your code properly. 2 minute efforts can engage more readers.

Comment: @niksofteng pending edit

Comment: `FindControl("ChkStatus")` -- Is every checkbox named "ChkStatus"?  What happens if you set a breakpoint on that line and check that `cb` is pointing to the correct check box each time.

Comment: @CapnJack your solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom since this turned out to be the solution, I posted it as an answer for others to see. Would you mind marking it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop to fully iterate through a collection of objects isn't the right tool for the job. Consider implementing LINQ's `foreach` loop to ensure you're going through every sing object.

For your example, instead of using `for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`, replace it with: `foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)`.

Comment: @Tom Select the little arrow underneath the vote buttons on my answer to accept it please : )

Comment: Yup it sure did. Thanks @CapnJack

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but my initial response would be that starting the service first may send the program on to another process and it never gets back to the original 'if' statement. Don't know if it'll work, or how to work it, but perhaps you would need to utilize different threads for each item?

Comment: Please put this as a comment if SO has given you that right.

Comment: The only reason this isn't a "comment" is because I need 50 reputation to add a comment. :/